# Passive verb after "to"

Tags: passive-voice, infinitives, ellipsis

I've encountered a sentence in an article which is strange for me, that is:

> 1. Some of the main issues **to address** are the following:

I think it should be:

> 2. Some of the main issues **to be addressed** are the following:

Am I wrong? If so, why? or it is just a simple mistake by the author?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both infinitives are fine.

The first is active, the second is passive. Both refer to future time in this context.

> Some of the main issues *to address at next week's meeting* are the following.

The infinitive here can have the meaning of *we need to/have to/must/should  address*.

and

> Some of the main issues *to be addressed at next week's meeting* are the following.